# is there an equivalent to cypress the dependsonmethods in testNG selenium?

Tags: cypress

Is there as simple as dependsonmethods used in test annotations in testNG equivalent in cypress?

example if in selenium test annotations it looks like this?

```
@Test()
public void tc1(){
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods= {"tc1"})
public void tc2(){
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods= {"tc1"})
public void tc3(){
}
```

if I am not mistaken this is somewhat like a parent function with 2 child functions that when the parent conditions inside is error then the two child functions will be skip.

in cypress I know there is callbacks and promise but depending on the kind of assertion you want it becomes more complex to me. I am new to cypress

please let me know if not too much to ask, can you at least provide an example

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cypress doesn't have `dependsOnMethods` like TestNG runner provides as both of them are different. But whatever you want to achieve, you can achieve through hooks provided by Mocha, as Cypress has Mocha as a test framework in itself.

***Note: This is what all you can do with hooks and your problem should be solved with below code. If you have any specific requirement, please mention it.***

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  before(() => {})
  beforeEach(() => { // put tc1() functionality
  })

  it('tc2 functionality', () => {
    // now tc2() depends on beforeEach block where tc1 functionality is done
  })

  it('tc3 functionality', () => {
    // now tc3() depends on beforeEach block where tc1 functionality is done
  })
})
```

Comment: A BIG THANK YOU FOR THIS HELP. I APPRECIATE THE HELP.. IT seems though that TestNG annotations dependsonmethods are way to simple than in cypress and I wish they would make something as simple as this

Comment: in this scenario, tc1 will run before each other tc. 
tc1 => tc2
tc1 => tc3
You're basically performing duplicated test runs all the time.
Rather than having this dependency, I'd recommend finding ways to have tc2 and tc3 not be depended on tc1